# TeXmaker in Ubuntu does not autocomplete bibliography items

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker, ubuntu, linux, auto-completion

I was using TeXstudio in Windows, now I switched to TeXmaker in Ubuntu. I love it, but one thing is missing.

In TeXstudio, whenever I type `\cite{` the autocomplete window appeared with the name of my bibliography items. And by bibliography items, I don't mean a separate .bib file. I just put them at the end of my document like this :

```
% ... beginning of the document
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{wikipedia_article} \begin{verbatim} http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_name \end{verbatim}
\bibitem{mikolajczyk_paper} K. Mikolajczyk (2005) "A Comparison of Affine Region Detectors" ,  International Journal of Computer Vision
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

But TeXmaker does not autocomplete the names `mikolajczyk_paper` and `wikipedia_article`. How can I make it work?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Why not use TeXstudio for Linux? http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/#download

Comment: Actually I liked TexMaker better (especially for the PDF preview window.) TexStudio in Windows was buggy in a sense. Alt + Tab was not switching to the editor window etc. But I will try the Linux version now. Thanks !

Comment: The Linux version is very stable. It has embedded pdf viewer or in a separated window.

Comment: may be post an feature request at http://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list or else put bibliography contents in `your-file.bib` and add `\bibliography{your-file.bib}` for autocompletion

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request.

Comment: There's no reason to thing Texmaker can do this, so it's a feature request. That's not on-topic, I'm afraid.